# Can't access to my TFS Server Console Web

Tags: visual-studio, tfs-2015

I installed TFS 2015 Update 3 in a server, everything works fine until I had to install the Office Developer Tools package (VS2015 it's installed in the server).

After the installation I can't access to the web console with my http://servername:8080/tfs. The following error in IE it's:
[Server Error in /tfs Applicaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm3AJ.png)

In VS2015 said it's an Error 500 Internal Error Server.
In VS2015 of my client machine said this error: [Error in VS2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MPv7.png)

Searching in internet about the possible solutions to this error, I tried this:

- Delete the cache files (Server and client machine).
- I checked my IIS and everything is running fine, even I restart the application.
- I Checked the Log Files but there's nothing information about the error.
- Even I changed the DNS gateway.
- Uninstall VS2015 in my server.

But the error persist....

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you access the TFS site on the local server? You could try to open your TFS in IE(`http://servername:8080/tfs`) on your TFS server machine not on a remote computer to see if you can connect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the **MSSQLSERVER** service is running. If it's stopped, just restart the service, then  try it again.

Also check other SQL server related services, make sure they are all running...

Or you can simply restart the TFS server and SQL server... then try it again.

[image]

If that still not work, just try to modify the `system.web` section of the TFS site `Web.config` file to see the actual error for further troubleshooting.  It should include the following lines...

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

Note, if you already have  compilation or customErrors lines in your Web.config, then replace them with these lines.